# How do you use the output from `info?` in a conditional?

Tags: rebol, rebol2

Given the following code:

```
file-info: info? %my_file.txt
```

How do you compare `file-info/type` in a conditional like:

```
if file-info/type = "directory" [ ... ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this all in one line

```
if 'file = get in file-info: info? %my-file 'type [
   ... is file ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In R2, You may want to try:

```
>> dir? %my_file.txt
== false
```

If R3, I wouldn't suggest that because it checks if a file ends with a slash.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it seems a little overcomplicated.

Comment: dir? simply checks an in memory value is either of type file or url and that the value ends with /. Info? checks the actual file and doesn't require the supplied name to end in "/" even if a directory.

Comment: Peter's comment about dir? is true of Rebol 3.  In Rebol 2, dir? does the info for you.  I've always used the Rebol 3 style test in Rebol 2 so as to avoid the info call on URL type "directories" (e.g FTP).

Comment: I believe Darrell is using R2, not R3

Comment: Yes, R2.  It turns out I needed `file? %my_file.txt` but that seems to return true even for directories.

Comment: Darrell The issue with `file? %my_file.txt` is that it is checking if it is a Rebol file value (i.e. does it start with `%`): from help:  `Returns TRUE for file values.`

Comment: So technically a directory is a file value?  Does it think of files in the Unix sense where everything is a file?

Comment: Well anything of the form `%x` is the file datatype, if that makes it clearer.  File extensions don't matter. As you see in Graham's example, you can use `info?` to get more specific information.  When you `read file` it will automatically evaluate whether it's a file or directory and return `binary!` or `block!` accordingly

Comment: Additionally you have `exists?` that will respond `true` if, natch, the file exists. A test then might be: `filetype: if exists? file [either dir? file ['directory]['file]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
if file-info/type = 'directory [ ... ]
```

(*Never underestimate your ability to realize the answer to your own question within 30 seconds of asking it.*)

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'dir rather than 'directory?